# Estimate the conditional variance after performing regression?

Tags: regression, variance

[image]

I have performed a nonlinear regression on the blue dots, the result is represented by the red dots. Now I would like to get an estimate of the variance at each value of x, so I can plot something like the two green lines (here they are drawn by hand). What is the most reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways how to cope with this.

1. The first option is to quantify the squares of errors $s_i=(y_i-\hat{y}_i)$ and to fit the variance model by means of nonlinear regression.
2. Another option is to adopt some methods that provide the estimates automatically such as Gaussian Processes, Gaussian Mixtures.
3. Finally, if you just want to see the e.g. 5-95% confidence interval, then quantile regression may be the option. If you can change the error function of your regression from squares to something else, you could get it easily.